# Looking for a solution for the question below

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Using a for loop, write code which populates this array with 100 evenly
spaced values of the function
() = 3^3 + 2^2 − 9
over the range 0 ≤  < 10

Comment: Can you just brute force it? Is there a constrain on complexity? Does this have a practical application or is this homework?

Comment: Its just homework

Comment: You have only input to the function X, is it a whole number or floating point? Aren't you missing parts of the assignment / constrain? Is this a full question?